# Appending Two CSV Files using built in csv module

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

I've two csv files to append & create a new csv file with the result. If I use 'binary' like 'rb' or 'wb' to read the write then it's throwing

> _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

If I use only 'r' & 'w' to read & write the following code giving me error like

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
with open('file1.csv','rt') as f, open('final.csv','wt')as out:
        first=csv.reader(f)
        final = csv.writer(out)
        for row in first:
                result=row[1]
                final.writerow(result)

with open('file21.csv','rt') as s, open('final.csv','wt')as out:
        second =  csv.reader(s)
        final = csv.writer(out)
        for row in second:
                result=row[1]
                final.writerow(result)
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileAppends.py", line 18, in <module>
    result=row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range @zsquare

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Join two csv files that's it. But both csv file has same header so I can copy headers from both. @Gijs

Comment: Use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611976/merge-one-column-from-variable-number-of-csv-files-into-one-csv-file/35612136#35612136.

Answer (score 0):

You have a row with no two values. Try `row[0]`, and check if you need to specify a delimiter.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileAppends.py", line 18, in <module>
    result=row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

sorry now showing this

Comment: You should show a part of your files, otherwise it's going to be hard to find your problem.

Comment: Two csv files with the same header/titles on the columns but different in values. Okay um trying to provide examples. @Gijs